# Running a pre-installation action on ClickOnce installation

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, clickonce, comaddin

We have a VSTO Excel COM-AddIn which is deployed as ClickOnce.

This uses post installation actions by implementing `IAddInPostDeploymentAction` and binding it in the manifest under `<vstav3:postActions>`.

However we now need a pre-installation action as well (to read registry and disable an existing AddIn).

Would this be possible with ClickOnce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to create a prerequisite that does what you want done, and deploy it as a prerequisite. ClickOnce itself does not provide a way to do pre-install commands.

You can use the Bootstrapper Manifest Generator to create a prerequisite package after creating the setup & deployment package to perform whatever commands you need completed.